# Fill in rows in excel, if other rows have data

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Is it possible to create a macro with a shortcut[ex:ctrl+Q] that will check column A if cells contain any data, and if they do, correspondent cell in column B should be filled in with current date.
This sould work over and over again, each time I open my file, continuing from the last cell which was completed previously in my last session.
I need this for my reporting on every 2 days or so. It would be faster than inserting current date each time and copying it to all cells.

Thanks!

Comment: The answer to any question when it comes to a macro is yes. But this is not a free coding community. Post your own attempt so we can help you.

Comment: Please give us your code to help u to correct it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it. For setting the shortcut, in excel, go to `tools/macro/macros` and then `options`.

Configure the CONFIG section of the code before you run it.

```
Sub fillCurrentDate()

Dim last_row As Long, start As Long, count As Long, next_row As Long

'CONFIG THIS BEFORE YOU RUN THE MACRO
start = 2 'in what row does the data starts?

last_row = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
next_row = Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1

If next_row <= start Then
    next_row = start
End If

'check if col A has data
If last_row > 1 Then
  
  'fill col B with corresponding data
  For count = next_row To last_row
    Cells(count, 2) = Date
  Next count

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: In case you are interested the recursive version is super fast now